# Optimizing a function available only through (monte-carlo) stochastic approximation

Tags: optimization, monte-carlo, stochastic-approximation

I am working on a problem where I want to estimate the maximum of a density that I can, in practice, evaluate (pointwisely) using a Monte-Carlo approach (because of intractable integrals). Obviously, these MC evaluations can go from almost-exact to coarse as a function of the numbers of particle  and thus of the computation time involved in the MC.

As the optimization must be performed on a very large number of data, being able to optimize using only "moderate particles estimate" (at least at the beginning of the optimization process) is crucial to me and I wonder if there exists dedicated optimization methods for such problems i.e. when the evaluations of the function to maximise are given as approximation with associated errors.

Comment: You may want to look into [response surface methodology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Response_surface_methodology), which is one of a number of approaches to the problem

Comment: @Glen_b. Thks for the input. Could you please give some key words for a few other approaches so that I can give some perspectives to my concern ? Thks in advance.

Comment: e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_optimization#Methods_for_stochastic_functions